# Contacts thumbnail photo path in monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-contacts

> How to get thumbnail contact photo in mono for android?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any checks, bit this will work:

[Xamarin.Contacts.Contact.GetThumbnail Method](http://betaapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aXamarin.Contacts.Contact.GetThumbnail)

This is Xamarin's contacts api. You use LINQ:
Here's a sample: [Introducing Xamarin.Contacts](http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/15/introducing-xamarin-contacts/) and here: [Send SMS to Contact using Xamarin.Mobile in Mono for Android](https://gist.github.com/1449755)

Comment: @user1245264 I added some samples for you to look at.